# Problem booting Windows 10 besides Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, windows-10

First I used windows 10 and then I have installed ubuntu 22.04.3 besides windows 10. When we start making choices, if we choose ubuntu the computer works normally but when we choose windwos10 it outputs the message

> setting partition type to 0*7
> error: can't find command 'drivemap'
> error: invalid EFI file path

So, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: See [help on boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). First, "Create a boot into summary" and when prompted, upload it. Make a note of the web link. Then try the "Recommended Repair". If it does not work, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1497449/edit) and add the link to the question.